# Is this half-smart way of verifying EdDSA signature secure?

Tags: implementation, eddsa

In the final step of verifying an EdDSA signature, `4[S]B` is compared to `[4]R + [4][k]A`.

Because I'm using the XYTZ - extended twisted Edwards coordinates, I want to, for efficiency reasons, do:

$$ Y(\text{Left}) \cdot Z(\text{Right}) = Y(\text{Right}) \cdot Z(\text{Left})$$,

But that leaves the X coordinates unchecked.

Can this check be secure?

Comment: For each $Y$ coordinate there can be two $X$ coordinates. Can you see that?

Comment: From the way [RFC-8032](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8032) describes the encoding and decoding of points, I can see that. I used the words "half-smart" because I'm not sure if the choice of X is significant in signature verification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the checking procedure itself is not [SUF-CMA](https://blog.cryptographyengineering.com/euf-cma-and-suf-cma/) as one can generate a second valid signature by replacing $R$ with $R+I$ where $I$ is a point of order divisible by 4.

By not checking the $X$ coordinate, you increase the number of secondary forgeries because $S$ can be replaced by $\ell-S$ *or* $R$ can be replaced with $R+I$ or both.

However, since the SUF-CMA security is already absent, the additional security loss is minimal. Only in cases where SUF-CMA is important and implementers decide to block it by not allowing signatures with duplicate $S$ values or by disallowing points $R$ that are not of order $\ell$ would your checking procedure introduce new attacks.